# Let $S$ be a completely regular semigroup, expressed as a semilattice $Y$ of completely simple semigroups $S_{\alpha}$ ($\alpha \in{Y})$

Tags: group-theory, ideals, semigroups

1. Show that, if $L$ is a left ideal of $S_{\alpha}$, then

$$L \cup [\cup \{S_{\beta} : \beta < \alpha\}]$$

is a left ideal of $S$.

2. Suppose now that $S= \mathcal{S}(Y;G_{\alpha};{\phi}_{\alpha,\beta})$ is a strong semi lattice of groups and that $L$ is a left ideal of $S$. Show that;

$$L \cap G_{\alpha} \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow \cup\{G_{\beta}: \beta \le \alpha\} \subseteq L$$

3. Show that $S$ is a Clifford semigroup if and only if it is regular and every one-sided ideal is a two sided ideal.

This is another question from Howies book. I struggle to understand what a semilattice is, and ideals are something I find hard to manipulate, so thought this would be a question for me to try and tackle (foolish I know!). Any help is obviously greatly appreciated, just trying to get a feel for how other people would approach this problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe @JamesMitchell could help? I'm not asking for a full complete answer necessairly, (though that would be wildly helpful!), just an idea of what is going on. Your other answers on semigroup questions on this site are explained in the precise way in which I follow semigroup theory, thats the only reason I tag you. Please don't take this as me ordering you to help! Its more of a compliment to your layout of proofs!

Comment: @JackBright does this tag work?

Comment: I'm not sure it worked, but I've seen it now, and I'm working on an answer.

Answer (score 2):

1) In a semilattice $\alpha\beta\leq \alpha$ and $\alpha\beta\leq \beta$, and so 
$\{S_{\beta}:\beta < \alpha\}$ is a (2-sided) ideal in $S$. A union of left ideals is a left ideal and so this part follows.

2) Suppose $L\cap G_{\alpha}\not=\varnothing$. Then there exists $g\in L\cap G_{\alpha}$.
If $\beta \leq \alpha$, then $\beta\alpha = \beta$. 
Hence for every $h\in G_{\beta}$, $hg^{-1}\in G_{\beta}$ and so $h=hg^{-1}\cdot g\in L$. 
It follows that $G_{\beta}\subseteq L$ for all $\beta\leq \alpha$, as required.

3) ($\Leftarrow$) Since every left ideal is a right ideal and every right ideal is a left ideal, this is in particular true for principal left and right ideals. If $x\in S$ is arbitrary, then $S^1x$ is the least left ideal containing $x$ and $xS^1$ is a left ideal containing $x$ by our assumption. Hence $S^1x\subseteq xS^1$. Dually, $S^1x\supseteq xS^1$ and so $S^1x=xS^1$. In other words, $\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{L}$ in $S$. Since $\mathscr{H}=\mathscr{L}\cap\mathscr{R}$ and $\mathscr{D}=\mathscr{L}\circ \mathscr{R}$, it follows that $\mathscr{H}=\mathscr{D}=\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{L}$.

Since $S$ is regular, every $\mathscr{D}$-class of $S$ contains an idempotent.
From $\mathscr{D}=\mathscr{H}$, every $\mathscr{H}$-class
also contains an idempotent. It follows that every $\mathscr{R}$-class
and every $\mathscr{L}$-class contain precisely one idempotent, and so $S$
is an inverse semigroup, and hence a Clifford semigroup.

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $S$ is a Clifford semigroup. Then it is completely
regular, and hence regular. It is also a strong semilattice of groups and so,
without loss of generality we can assume that $S=\mathcal{S}(Y;
G_{\alpha}:\phi_{\alpha, \beta})$ as in part 2.

We will show that every right ideal is a left ideal. A dual argument shows that
every left ideal is a right ideal, and hence every one-sided ideal is a
two-sided ideal.

Since every right ideal is
a union of principal right ideals, it suffices to show that every principal left
ideal is a right ideal. Let $x\in S$ and consider $L=S^1x$ (the principal left
ideal generated by $x$). Since $S$ is a union of groups, it follows that $x\in
G_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in Y$. Hence by 2, $\bigcup\{G_{\beta}:\beta\leq
\alpha\}$ is a subset of $L$. On the other hand, if $y\in L$, then $y=zx$ for
some $z\in S^1$. But $z\in G_{\gamma}$ and so $y=zx\in G_{\gamma\alpha}\subseteq
L$ (since $\gamma\alpha\leq \alpha$). Thus $L = \bigcup\{G_{\beta}:\beta\leq
\alpha\}$.

So, if $y\in L$ and $s\in S$ are arbitrary, then $y\in G_{\beta}$, $\beta\leq
\alpha$, and $s\in G_{\gamma}$, $\gamma\in Y$. This implies that $yz\in
G_{\beta\gamma}\subseteq L$, since $\beta\gamma\leq \beta\leq \alpha$, and so
$L$ is a right ideal as required.

Comment: does all of this answer just use knowledge from Howies book? I dont follow what has happened in part 1 really, and in part 2, why does $h=hg^{-1}g \in{L}$? Sorry, I really am trying to understand, just finding it quite complicated. Thank you so much for taking time to help me out though!

Comment: Yes, it does only use knowledge from Howie's book. As for the second question $g\in L$ and we are left multiplying by an element of $S$. The better question is why does $hg^{-1}g=h$?

Comment: Well presumably that is because $gg^{-1}=e$ the identity in $G_{\alpha}$?

Comment: It is but remember $h\not\in G_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Ok so i follow 2.) now besides the fact that $h=hg^{-1}g \in{L}$? $hg^{-1} \in{G_\beta}$ so does this mean that $hg^{-1} \in{S}$ and so using the fact $L$ is a left ideal and $x \in{L} we have $h=hg^{-1}g \in{L}$?

Comment: And in 1.), why do we have that $\{S_{\beta}: \beta \le \alpha\}$ is a two sided ideal?

Comment: You're right about why $h\in L$. For the second question, if $s\in S$ and $t\in S_{\delta}$ with $\delta\leq \alpha$, then there exist $\gamma\in Y$ such that $t\in S_{\gamma}$. Hence $st, ts\in S_{\delta\gamma}$ and, since $\delta\gamma\leq \delta\leq \alpha$, $st, ts\in \{S_{\beta}: \beta\leq \alpha\}$, making it an ideal.

Comment: if $t \in{S_\delta}$ how is $t \in{S_\gamma}$ as well? or is that meant to be $s \in{S_\gamma}$

Comment: Right, that was a typo it should read $s\in S_\gamma$.

Comment: Also, for he first part of 3.), we have shown its an inverse semigroup, but do we not also need to show $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x$?

Comment: In an inverse semigroup where $\mathscr{L}=\mathscr{R}$, $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x$ follows since they are both idempotents in the same $\mathscr{R}$-class, and since there is only one idempotent in that $\mathscr{R}$-class they have to be equal.

Comment: And why because every H-class contains an idempotent does it mean that every L-class and R-class must contain exactly one? Sorry, not trying to be difficult, just trying to undertsand.

Comment: No worries! We showed that $\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{L}=\mathscr{H}=\mathscr{D}$ in this semigroup, and it is true in every semigroup that an $\mathscr{H}$-class contains at most 1 idempotent. So, in this particular semigroup every $\mathscr{D}$-, $\mathscr{L}$-, and $\mathscr{R}$-class (they are all $\mathscr{H}$-classes!) contains at most one idempotent.

Comment: Ahh i see, thank you so much! Sorry I'm being dense, its tough to get my head around it all! So one final (maybe!) question, why are $xx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}x$ in the same R-class?

Comment: Can you show that $xx^{-1}\mathscr{R}x$ and $x^{-1}x\mathscr{L}x$? Then use that $\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{L}$.

Comment: Oh ok thank you so much once again!

Comment: In the second part of 3. should it read' it suffices to show every principal left ideal is a principal right ideal'?

Comment: Either way is fine for the last question. If every principal left ideal is a right ideal (not necessarily principal), then every left ideal is a right ideal.

Comment: ahh okay thank you. Also, in part 1.), does the fact $\beta$ is strictly less than $\alpha$ change the argument at all?

Comment: I don't think it has any significance.

Comment: In the first part, $L$ is not an ideal of $S$, but solely of $S_{\alpha}$, so you cannot simply argue that their union is an ideal in $S$, this would just work if $L$ would be an ideal in the whole semigroup $S$! Or am I missing something?